# dynamoDB Query of Global Secondary Index with HashKeyValue and RangeKeyCondition not working JavaScript

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I am executing following dynamoDB query using JavaScript:

```
dynamoDB.query({
        "TableName"    :"table_name",
        "IndexName": "Approval-Date-index",
        "HashKeyValue": {"Approval": {"AttributeValueList": [{"S": 'Approved'}],"ComparisonOperator": "EQ"}},
        "RangeKeyCondition" : {"Date" : {"AttributeValueList": [{"S": "0"}]}},
        // "ScanIndexForward"  : true,
        "AttributesToGet":["Id","Url","userName","userPicture","Title","Date","Type","Description"]
    },
    function(error, result) 
    {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I am getting following error:

> ValidationException:1 validation error detected: Value null at 'rangeKeyCondition.comparisonOperator' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null

Answer (score 0):

To me it gave me the same error 
**"ValidationException:1 validation error detected: Value null at 'rangeKeyCondition.comparisonOperator' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null"**
What I made was to update the Dynamodb SDK and I solved the problems